# Question related to an Idea

Tags: discussion

Will questions related to developement, accuracy and usage of an Idea be considered on-topic on Chemistry S.E.? It might help us in developement, increasing accuracy & efficiency, correct usage of new innovative ideas.

Obviously ideas should be related to chemistry somehow..!! :p

For eg.
Today an idea crossed my mind. I was thinking about basing liquid vaporiser, that kills mosquitoes, on priciple of Vapour pressure. By this way we can control concentration of vapours in a closed room so that it does not affect us in any means. So, when this idea came to my mind, first question that I raised to myself was 'Is it possible?' (very obvious question :|) and then 'What kind of liquid I would need for that?' and so on. So, if the idea based questions become on-topic on chemistry S.E., it would become much easier to develope benificial Ideas in public interest..!! :)

Comment: Hi there! This is a good conversation to raise on meta, but if you happen to have an example you could add, it'll make it that much easier for folks to discuss. :)

Comment: @Ana Hevesi : edited original post! Hope it helps.